# How to make a javascript callback function execute first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code (that I have stripped and simplified):

```
function myOrder() {
        setLocation(); // sets a value for global variable 'location'  
                       // using GET         

        $.post('http://111.111.111.111/order', {
                Item: Chair,
                Price: 50, 
                Location: location;
                                               })
}
```

The problem is that this function executes the post() code before the setLocation() callback function has finished.

I need the setLocation() function to finish first, so it can assign a global variable for 'location', which is then used as a value in the POST part.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Thanks

EDIT: To clarify: 
setLocation() is a GET request, that gets the current location via GPS and stores it under a global variable name 'location'.

So what I think is happening is that the myOrder() method POSTS before the callback function has finished its GET response.

Comment: Could you add the implementation of `setLocation`?

Comment: Take a look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). The function setLocation should return one.

Comment: setLocation should return a Promise which should be resolved when the function is executed successfully. You can add the post request in the .then() handler  .

Comment: After your edit I can only repeat: please provide the *implementation* of `setLocation` (code, not words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not provide the implementation of `setLocation`, I'll assume you use `$.get` or some similar jQuery function (`$.ajax`, `$.getJSON`, ...).

In that case, do not use the callback function of `$.get`, and do not store the response data a global variable, but *return* `$.get(...)` because it is a promise:

```
function setLocation() {
    // Return the promise object returned by $.get, $.getJSON, $.ajax, ...
    //  instead of using the callback function, and don't store the result
    //  in a global variable
    return $.get("myurl").then(function (data) {
        // As you did not provide the code, this serves only as example. The 
        // way you extract the latitude and longitude from the response may be
        // different. Adapt as needed:
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var lat = data.result[0].lat;
        var lng = data.result[0].lng;
        // Return value will be the promised value: adapt the format as needed,
        // This will become the location variable content in your other function 
        return { lat, lng }; 
    });
}
function myOrder() {
    // Use the `then` method on the jQuery promise, and return
    //   the result of the `then` method again, so you can chain
    //   on myOrder() as well...
    return setLocation().then(function (location) {
        // Return the `$.post` result:
        return $.post('http://111.111.111.111/order', {
            Item: Chair,
            Price: 50, 
            Location: location;
       });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. But my setLocation() function doesn't return anything. It gets a location using openstreetmap and sets global variable of 'location' to an address converted to a longitude. How would I implement this if setLocation() doesn't return anything? Thanks

Comment: My point is that you should *change* `setLocation` so that it *does* return something, and does *not* set a global variable (which is bad practice anyway).

Comment: Hmm I see. My setLocation() method sets two global variables (for longitude and latitute). How would I make the method return these two? My $.post code actually posts these two bits of info.

Comment: Why don't you just post the essential parts of your `setLocation` function, so I can take that as starting point and transform it in my answer? It will be easier than talking about it like we are doing now. The idea is that you either don't process the response at all in `setLocation` (and leave that to the caller), or you do, but then you must `return` it (maybe an array with two values) *inside* a `then` method callback.

Comment: I have added some sample code on how you could treat longitude and latitude, but without seeing your code, I cannot know how you currently get those values via the response. But the idea should be clear. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry had some problems with other parts of my project! This works fantastic and thanks for the sample!

Answer (score 2):

Use async flow

```
function setLocation() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // I do my stuff

    // I finished
    resolve();
  });
}

function myOrder() {
        setLocation().then(() => {
          $.post('http://111.111.111.111/order', {
                  Item: Chair,
                  Price: 50, 
                  Location: location;
                                                 })        
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `setLocation` function is an asynchronous function, you will need to change it to receive a callback function after it completes.

```
function myOrder() {
   setLocation(function() {
      $.post('http://111.111.111.111/order', {
            Item: Chair,
            Price: 50, 
            Location: location
      });
   });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This didn't work. Do I need to change anything in the header of the setLocation() method?

Comment: @teep Exactly, you need to change the setLocation function to receive a callback argument, so when it finishes its execution, it must trigger the callback. It will be something like that: `function setLocation(callback) { doMyStuffHere(); callback(); }`

Comment: Still won't work! It builds fine etc, but the $.post still executes first. I setup alerts in the setLocation method and they show after the $.post alerts! Any idea? EDIT: fixed, had to place the callback() in the IF statement I created. thanks

Comment: I've created an example on how could be: https://pastebin.com/QBcjsktn. Hope this helps clarify.